# Read in arbitrary file as string, then save back to file? Always corrupted

Tags: r

I'm trying to simply read in an arbitrary file into R as a string. Then save it to another location.

```
data = readLines("/path_to_file/")
con = file("/new_path_to_file", "w")
writeLines(data, con)
close(con)
```

Every time the new file is corrupted (testing with this image: http://lacuadramagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/sangeh-monkey-forest-101.jpg).

I also tried `readChar` but depending on the file, I get a UTF-8 error.

I want to be able to do this with any file - image, text, etc. This is part of a larger analysis (so file.copy doesn't cut it), but I can't even get the basic read/write mechanism down. Should be simple but getting stumped.

Comment: I do other things in between, like base64 encode/processing/decode. The trick is I want to import an arbitrary file as a string, which is easy in python (open(filepath).read()), but I can't seem to do that in R.

Comment: You only said you want to read it and save it. If you want to do other things between, you should say that in your question.

Comment: Title: "read in arbitrary file as string, then save back to file"

Comment: Which part isn't working?  If it is the writing, try `writeLines` rather than `cat`.

Comment: @BryanHanson tried writelines too! isn't working with an image :-/.

Comment: I think we need further clarification as to how it doesn't work.  Does the writing fail, or you end up with a corrupted file that won't open?  Oh, I see you added that the file was corrupted.  There could be a lot of really complicated reasons for that.

Comment: @BryanHanson ...sorry - I get a corrupted file that doesn't open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with binary data here, not character data. Most likely you should be working with

```
setwd("~/../Desktop")
fn<-"sangeh-monkey-forest-101.jpg"
img<-readBin(fn, raw(), file.info(fn)$size)
writeBin(img, "out.jpg")
```

You can try converting to character with functions like `rawToChar(img)` but since R strings can't contain null values (which your's does -- `which(img==0)`) you can't really represent this as a properly encoded string.

Comment: Does readBin limit the number of characters I can import to 10000 or am I misreading that? https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readBin.html

Comment: I believe that message is specifically if you are using `readBin` to read character data from a file. If you read `raw` data I don't believe that restriction applies. I tried the code above on the sample image and it worked just fine and `length(img)` was 111683.